# Wallpaper picture location - Lake with mountains

Tags: where-on-earth, alps, lock-screens

There is a Windows 10 lock screen wallpaper that really caught my attention:

[image]

Does anyone know the location of this picture?

Comment: The mountain in the far background has a distinctive double peak that might help in identifying it.  The landscape looks similar to the Rocky Mountains here in Colorado, but that doesn't necessarily mean much.

Comment: I sort of suspect it's a composite image, with the background mountains having been inserted, but I hope to be proven wrong.

Comment: I'm going along with @MarkMayo on this one.  A composite of three images...   The sign identifying the lake is on a path that goes straight into a ravine!  The hikers are dressed for a day hike, but not above the timber line.  The hewn path suggests the John Muir trail, but the mountains are more like Idaho or Tahoe.  They worked hard on getting the reflection right, but there's an unexplained peak on the far end.  So I'll guess this is the back of the Ponderosa Ranch and the photo was taken by Joe Cartwright.

Comment: It looks like Patagonia-ish to me. Although, I've never been there... not yet.

Comment: I agree it is likely a composite, though not for @GayotFow reasons, as I have day hiked above tree line in the Rockies and Alaska and the trail coming in towards the sign doesn't seem out of place.  But there is a distinctive blend line between the foreground and the mountain background.  And also in a few spots along the lakeshore.

Comment: Find the actual file on disk and see if there is any meta-data in the file.  It may list the photographer or other information that could be used to further your search.  The Windows 7 Wallpapers list the photographer in metadata, so it's a good place to look.

Comment: @JPhi1618 thanks for the tip, that's how I ended up finding the location.

Comment: I usually use https://www.tineye.com for reverse image searching, but now even google images are doing that.

Comment: Here is [another picture](http://www.figedansletemps.com/galerie/galleries/Montagne/Grandes_rousses/LacduPontet/DSC_2707.jpg) taken from almost the same position in wintertime: [![Pontet Lake](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rxOFI.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rxOFI.jpg)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The image was taken at [Pontet Lake](http://www.lagrave-lameije.com/en/fiche/patrimoine/pontet_lake-352263-513), in the Hautes-Alpes in southeastern France ([45.051247, 6.351562](https://www.google.cz/maps/place/Lac+du+Pontet,+05480+Villar-d'Ar%C3%A8ne,+France/@45.0508619,6.3507307,18z)).

The author is [Florian Blondeau](https://500px.com/floragnarok). Here's [another image](https://500px.com/photo/8320744/pontet-lake-by-florian-blondeau) of the lake by the same photographer:

[image: Pontet Lake]

Comment: How were you able to search for that? I tried using reverse-image search but just found millions of posts about Win10

Comment: Found the photographer's name in the metadata.